# как сделать заголовки h1 и h2 одинаковые по размеру?

Tags: python, html, django

сделал в django простенькую страницу с двумя заголовками и текстом. но первый больше, чем второй, хотя в стиле указаны шрифты одинакового размера.
вот стиль:

```
<style>
        h1 {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 165%;
        color:#a7e924be;
        border: 3px outset #a7e924be;
        padding: 6px;
        }
        h2 {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 165%;
        color:#006400;
        border: 3px outset #006400;
        padding: 6px;
        }
</style>
```

вот код в пайтон:

```
def zagolovok1(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>География (от др.-греч. γεωγραφία «землеописание», через лат. geographia или польск. geografia) — комплекс естественных и общественных наук, изучающих структуру, функционирование и эволюцию географической оболочки, взаимодействие и распределение в пространстве природных и природно-общественных геосистем и их компонентов.</h1>'
                        '<h2>География изучает поверхность Земли, её природные условия, распределение на ней природных объектов, населения, экономических ресурсов, это сфера территориального распространения чего-либо.</h2>'
                        '<style>h1{ font-family:"Times New Roman",Times, font-size: 165%; color:#a7e924be;border: 3px outset #a7e924be; padding: 6px; } h2 {font-family:"Times New Roman",Times, serif;font-size: 165%;color:#006400; border: 3px outset #006400; padding: 6px; } </style>')
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/h1

Comment: Я не мастер HTML, но обычно `style` находится в `head`, а не в `body` (не говоря о том, что ваш HTML не полный). Возможно `style` можно вставлять в `body`, но (возможно) он должен быть перед тэгами, которые он "стилизирует".

Answer (score 0):

`<h2 style='...'>География изучает...</h2>`Если уж и делать через HttpResponse , то пропишите стили в самих тегах, к примеру